# NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404) with quickblox

Tags: ios

NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_tags.json?page=1&per_page=100&tags=dev, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<20>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}

.....I am getting this type of error , please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

You have to create session First.

To get rid of this you should wait when create session requests will be finished and perform next request:

```
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];
```

...

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
     if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBAAuthSessionCreationResult.class]){

         // you got token here - perform any other requests after this

         [QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:... delegate:self];

     }
}
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: I was getting this error: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/958 - can you help me into this? If you are aware with QuickBlox iOS setup.